# Secondary Links in Blocks in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

Is there any  way by which secondary links/primary links can be printed in a block ?
In block-my_module.tpl.php i have this piece of code

```
<?php if (isset($secondary_links)) { ?><?php print theme('links', $secondary_links, array('class' => 'links', 'id' => 'subnavlist')) ?><?php } ?>
```

Which i took from a sys theme , i  can print this in a page.tpl.php file but not in a block file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a listing of what variables are available in each template by default
http://www.minezone.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/drupal-theming-cheat-sheet.pdf

And here is a link that shows how to pass variables between template areas
http://drupal.org/node/223430